# How do I download and upload a file from an authenticated SharePoint site in an android app

Tags: android, sharepoint

I am unable to download and then read a file from a Sharepoint site.

I tried using download manager and have the Sharepoint URL passed into the Download Manager
The Download manager downloads the file in the Download folder of Android.
But it is not readable from the same location always highlights file does not exist.

I want my program to read and write to the file in my download folder in android

Comment: Of course its readable if you downloaded it. And who is highlighting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.